# Can we say that the case A is also fundamental

Tags: logic, terminology

We have two non equivalent mathematical statements A and B.

The case A is proved to be true. While the truth of the case B is unknown.

By using the proof by contradiction, assuming that B is false, then we get A is false. Then we get the implication $A⇒B$. In this case A is stronger than B. Assuming that B is fundamental in the sense that it imply many other results.

My **question** is: Can we say that the case A is also fundamental.

Comment: Not very clear... If we have proved $\lnot B \to \lnot A$, this is equivalent to $A \to B$. Thus, having proved $A$, we may deduce $B$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: The exercice is about B being fundamental.

Comment: What is your precise definition of a statement being fundamental?

Comment: "Fundamental" is not defined... If you mean that $A$ implies $B$, then YEs. And if the two are **not** equivalent, this means that $B$ does not imply $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, results are fundamental because they are one of the first non-trivial results that imply a world of other results.

For example, take the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra F.T.A (not just because it has the word fundamental in it's name).  This theorem states that any polynomial of real or complex coefficients is fully factorable in $\mathbb{C}$.

On the one hand, it is fundamental because it is such a useful and powerful tool that many mathematics could not be born without it.

But on the other hand, you need to build quite a bit of machinery (usually basic complex analysis) to prove it.  So there are many results that F.T.A **depends on**, some of which may be seen as fundamental, and many of which may not